# Prove $F(t)^2-G(t)^2=2tF(t)G(t)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, lebesgue-integral

> Let $F, G:]0,\infty[ \to \mathbb R$ be 
>   $$F(t):=\int_{[0,\infty[}e^{-tx^2}\cos{x^2}d\lambda(x)$$ and $$G(t):=\int_{[0,\infty[}e^{-tx^2}\sin{x^2}d\lambda(x)\,.$$
>   Prove that
>   $$F(t)^2-G(t)^2=2tF(t)G(t)\,.$$

Note:

$F(t)^2-G(t)^2=(\int_{[0,\infty[}e^{-tx^2}\cos{x^2}d\lambda(x))^2-(\int_{[0,\infty[}e^{-tx^2}\sin{x^2}d\lambda(x))^2$

Specifically looking at

$(\int_{[0,\infty[}e^{-tx^2}\cos{x^2}d\lambda(x))^2=\int_{[0,\infty[}e^{-tx^2}\cos{x^2}d\lambda(x)\times \int_{[0,\infty[}e^{-tx^2}\cos{x^2}d\lambda(x)$

am I allowed to state: $\int_{[0,\infty[}e^{-tx^2}\cos{x^2}d\lambda(x)\times \int_{[0,\infty[}e^{-tx^2}\cos{x^2}d\lambda(x)=\int_{[0,\infty[^2}e^{-tx^2}\cos{x^2}d\lambda^{2}(x)$? And then I assume I should substitute $y = x^2$

$\int_{[0,\infty[}2x(\int_{[0,\infty[}e^{-ty}\cos{y}dy)dx$

I can integrate $e^{-y}\cos{y}$ tediously by parts, however, I am not sure what to do with the parameter $t$ in $e^{-ty}\cos{y}$, as in the above case.

Any support is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess the title should be $F^2(t)-G^2(t) (= \frac{\pi t}{1+t^2})=2tF(t)G(t)$.

Comment: Have you tried to use Euler's identity $e^{iy} = \cos y + i \sin y$ within this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute $F$ and $G$ directly, since 
$$
H(t) = F(t) + i G(t) = \int_0^\infty e^{-tx^2} \left( \cos x^2 + i \sin x^2 \right) dx =
\int_0^\infty e^{(i - t)x^2} \, dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{t - i}} \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \, .
$$
Then 
$$
F^2(t) - G^2(t) = \Re H^2(t) = \Re \frac{\pi}{4(t-i)} = \frac{\pi}{4} \frac{t}{t^2 + 1}
$$ 
and 
$$ 2 F(t) G(t) = \Im H^2(t) = \Im \frac{\pi}{4(t-i)} = \frac{\pi}{4} \frac{1}{t^2 + 1} \, .
$$
It follows that $F^2(t) - G^2(t) = 2tF(t)G(t)$.

Comment: Thank you, that makes it a lot clearer. I was told this proof should be used in the context of solving $\int_{[0,\infty[}\cos{x^2}d\lambda(x)$ but I fail to see it

Comment: That integral may now be obtained as $F(0) = \lim_{t \to 0} F(t)$. However it's not a Lebesgue integral, so care must be taken :)

Comment: Can you elaborate further on that statement? Why is it not a lebesgue integral?

Comment: Because the absolute value of the function is not integrable.